# Unhandled JSP exception in Filter

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a filter configured for a JSP. In the filter I am using HTTPResponseWrapper for modifying the response to the user. My code in doFilter method of Filter is:

```
CharArrayWrapper responseWrapper = new CharArrayWrapper(
        (HttpServletResponse) response); 
chain.doFilter(request, responseWrapper);
String responseString = responseWrapper.toString();

System.out.println("responseString ********************* "
        + responseString);

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.write(responseString);
```

The CharArrayWrapper class is:

```
public class CharArrayWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

    private CharArrayWriter charWriter;

    public CharArrayWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
        charWriter = new CharArrayWriter();
    }

    public PrintWriter getWriter() {
        return (new PrintWriter(charWriter));
    }

    public String toString() {
        return (charWriter.toString());
    }

    public char[] toCharArray() {
        return (charWriter.toCharArray());
    }

}
```

If the JSP for which the above filter is configured executes fine, there is no problem in the filter too and I can see the sysout on the console.

On the other hand, when there is some unhandled exception raised in the JSP scriptlet code (its an old application) and I invoke chain.doFilter(request, responseWrapper);,  I get a NullPointerException. Is there any way by which I can know in my filter that there was an unhandled exception raised in the JSP

Comment: maybe I do not understand the question, You can just add a try catch in your filter...

Comment: sometimes, your brain gets too restricted in thinking and that's what has happened with me.Thanks @Home, that's the way to go. Pls. post ur comment as answer and I shall accept it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply wrap the code in a `try catch` block like this:

```
CharArrayWrapper responseWrapper = new CharArrayWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response); 
try {
    chain.doFilter(request, responseWrapper);

    String responseString = responseWrapper.toString();

    System.out.println("responseString ********************* " + responseString);

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.write(responseString);

} catch (Exception e) {

    // do whatever is necessary (logging etc.)
}
```

There are some other things to consider:

- `getWriter` always creates a new `PrintWriter`, this may lead to some side effects as other components might call `getWriter` as well. I'd create an instance variable.
- the character array approach has one disadvantage, you 'cache' the whole response instead of streaming it back to the client, given large JSPs this might have impact on your JVM heap.